# Is is possible to synchronously check whether a script exists in the browser's cache from JS?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a script (A) that wants to load another script (B), but only if B is already available in the browser's cache. (For example, maybe A would load a different script (C) if B wasn't there.) Is it possible to know that?

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind wrt resource loading is [Service Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API). Aside from that, there is no API that lets you query the browser cache.

Comment: How would the script be available at browser cache? _"Let's say I have a script that wants to load another script, but only if it's already available in the browser's cache."_ Which script are you referring to being in browser cache? What is "it's"? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Synchronously? I don't think so.

Comment: Added some identifiers to try to make in clearer for you, @guest271314

Comment: By "browser cache" are you referencing `Cache` object or an object loaded by "script (B)" that is defined in browser?

Comment: The cache as displayed in the network tab. I.e. script B is able to load without a network request.

Comment: Is there a real use case or would a 50% chance be enough?

Comment: The real use case is optimizing the performance of a third-party script in a way that allows it to be broken up into smaller modules without losing performance to a lot of asynchronous request/response loops. ServiceWorkers seem promising.

Comment: I don't see how knowing if the script is cached would help in your scenario... Either you need its content and you load it either you don't need it. (Sorry for nitpicking, I'm sure you've got your reasons, but that sounds too much of an XY problem to me and I don't bite the load an other script part)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by an XY problem. If there were a reliable way to know, I might be able to make a synchronous xhr request in the case where it's in the cache without adversely affecting page performance, but I wouldn't want to make it in other cases, because sync requests are evil™. I'm doubtful that I'd want to go down that road, but I'm experimenting with it.

Comment: [XyProblem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). In any case, don't do an synchronous XHR call, instead, learn to handle asynchronicity. And if you want to load scripts, don't use xhr either, directly use `<script>` elements.

Comment: It's not an XY problem; it's an experimental scenario where standard best practices may not apply. I know how to handle asynchronicity.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the better way to solve your problem is to save information about all uploaded scripts in localStorage. Then on next page load check each scripts status and if scripts status is cached try to load it from cache.

That's it!

Comment: And how can you tell I didn't hard refreshed the page?

Comment: I've thought about stashing the content of script B in local storage instead of relying on the browser cache, but other than that I don't think I could count on my stored statuses staying in sync with whatever the browser happens to have done.

Comment: Why don't you want to save only cached script urls to your scripts in array  in localStorage? Something like this: localStorage.cachedUrls = "['scriptUrl1','scriptUrl2','scriptUrl3']".

Comment: Because localStorage.cachedUrls can easily become out of date compared with what's actually in the cache.